# sum/aggregate data based on dates, R

Tags: r, date

I have a data set like following:

```
Date            Country    Item    Qty    Value
15-04-2014      SE         08888   2      20
28-04-2014      SE         08888   2      20
05-05-2014      SE         08888   6      80
```

I want to sum quantity values when the dates are before the 1 May, and the aggregated value (the sum) should be marked as 1 May.

I tried `ddply`, but it sums all the value regardless of the dates.

```
ddply(se, .(se$Item), summarize, Qty = sum(se$Qty), Value = sum(se$Value))
```

Also tried subsetting by the date, with no big success.

```
se$Date <- as.Date(as.character(se$Date))
se_q <- subset(se,se$Date <= 01-05-2014)

Date         Country Item     Qty    Value
0015-04-20   SE      08888    2      20
0028-04-20   SE      08888    2      20
0005-05-20   SE      08888    6      80
```

How could I add the date argument in the code? or how could I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` for example:

```
require(dplyr)

> df %.% 
    filter(Date <= as.Date("2014-05-01")) %.% 
 #  group_by(Item) %.%                       #you can add this line if you need to group by Item (it will appear in the output then)
    summarize(Date = as.Date("2014-05-01"), Qty = sum(Qty), Value = sum(Value))

#        Date Qty Value
#1 2014-05-01   4    40
```

The problem in your `subset` is that you are not telling R that `2014-05-01` is a `Date`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply :-)

Comment: I ran the code, and get the following message
Date Qty
1  2014-05-01  10
Warning message:
In filter_impl(.data, dots(...), environment()) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for "<="

Comment: Did you convert your `Date` column to `Date` format?  try `df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d-%m-%Y")`